# AngularJS - Trouble with directive changing value in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm getting large images from an API in my main controller.

I have a directive that successfully lets me know when each image is loaded:

```
app.directive('imageonload', function() {
    return {
        controller: "mainController",
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {   
                alert("loaded");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I created a loading screen with a simple

```
$scope.loading = true;
```

in my main controller.

If I set the loading to false in the directive (replacing the alert), **it only seems to affect the child scope and never the parent** (according to Batarang extension).

I included:

```
scope: {
        loading: '@'
},
```

in my directive, but it still doesn't remove the loading screen.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="images" imageonload loading="loading">
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`@` sets up one way data binding.  So if the parent changes the child does too, but not the other way.

Using `=` will give you two way binding.  So when your directive changes `loading` that change will be reflected on the parent scope.

Thus you want:

```
scope: {
   loading: '='
},
```